# Java / Unable to write multiple files to .zip

Tags: java

-> I cannot figure this out.  I am able to write one file to a zip file, but I cannot write more than one.  I cannot seem to get this to work out.  Here is the code that will write one file into a .zip:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(screenShotList.get(0));
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\NameOfZip.zip"));
zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(screenShotFileNameList.get(0)));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int byteRead;
while((byteRead=fin.read(buffer))>0) {
     zout.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
}
zout.closeEntry();
zout.close();
fin.close();
```

-> Here is me trying to loop it, but this code fails.  It does not even write a .zip to the file path:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("MyZipFile.zip");
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
for (int i=0; i<screenShotList.size(); i++) {
     File fileToZip = screenShotList.get(i);
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
     ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(screenShotFileNameList.get(i));
     zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

     byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
          zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
     }
     fis.close();
}
zipOut.close();
fos.close();
```

-> I have tried so many different things.  What am I doing wrong?

I have tried moving the classes in and out of the loop.  I have tried random stuff from the internet.  I am clearly missing a key point here.

Comment: To fix this, you can create a new FileOutputStream object for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I tried this code and it works for me. What are the files you are trying to zip?

Comment: @CardinalSystem no; `close()` implies flush. Your suggestion _never_ solves a problem (unless the streams you are using are quite broken. ZipOutputStream is not broken, at least, specifically, not like that).

Comment: @SiNGH_VJ That advice does not make sense.

Comment: @Michael Nothing in the code indicates a problem, and using that code myself, it produces zips with multiple entries just fine. You have a more general problem of not using try-with, and `fis.transferTo(zipOut)` is a lot simpler than the loop you made, but that's just code quality issues, does not explain what you say you observe. Elaborate on what you are doing and what 'unable to' actually means. Do you get an error? A corrupt zip? Nothing happens and no zip file appears?

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work. Here is my code:

```
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\MyZipFile.zip"));
for (int i = 0; i < screenShotList.size(); i++) {
    File fileToZip = screenShotList.get(i);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(screenShotFileNameList.get(i));
    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    fis.close();
    zipOut.closeEntry();
}
zipOut.close();
```

Comment: I could suggest explaining what the problem was and how you resolved it.

Comment: This code is identical, other than that it specifies a full path for the zip out file instead of a relative path. So the solution is, evidently, "I was not aware where the CWD for my java process is", which isn't explained by this answer, nor does it seem particularly relevant to zip files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).